# Why doesn't my profile show up with the new format on this site?

Tags: bug, profile-page

I've noticed many other sites have a new profile, that among other things leads to items like tracking tag badges and other badges. Every other site that I participate on regularly has the new format, but for some reason I don't see it here. I know there was a configuration that happened initially, but I'm not sure why this one site would be the only site that I belong to that doesn't have it. Am I going crazy, or is there something unique about this site that doesn't allow for the new profile? Is there something unique to my profile that doesn't show the new page? If so, how can I change it?

I'm referring to this page, which shows examples of the new page. [Profile Page Makeover, Part 3: the Prototype returns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244238/155668)

Comment: Because we suck and SE hate us, probably

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed

Comment: My take is that the sudden pressure to get some of the smaller sites graduated (which requires fancy site designs) has massively impacted on SE's ability to roll out the new user pages.

Comment: Don't know how long it will last, but we can be thankful for the reprieve. The new format is confusing and what you are really looking for is well hidden.

Comment: And now it's arrived!

Answer (score 3):

Allegedly it's because our site has funky custom CSS and any attempt to do anything clever results in the whole site falling over in a quite embarrassing way.

I've raised this on several occasions and the answer is that we get the usual "[we're working on it and it'll happen in a few weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed) messages back.

Note that we're not the *only* site in this position.

---

[This comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed#comment843552_253359) from the SE design team is also quite instructive;

> We were cranking on these, but some other design stuff that was more
>   time sensitive slowed the rollout a bit. You should see these picking
>   up pace again pretty soon.

Comment: I guess they'll complete it in [6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/252593).